How do I use jstree with differently named id/parent fields?
To learn how to use jstree I tried with the following json example,  and it works very fine indeed.
id:1
text:"AAA"
parent:"#"
color:"red"
type:"root"
 
id:2
text:"BBB"
parent:1
color:"grey"
type:"child"

I need to use the following json instead (fatherId:uniqueId instead of parent:id, level instead of types)
id:1
uniqueId: u1
text:"AAA"
fatherId:"#"
level:"basic"
-----
id:2
uniqueId: u2
text:"BBB"
fatherId: u1
level:"sub_basic"

I do not see how I may configure jstree as to use the latter json (I would rather not serialize it differently).
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/discussions/2791
